# ASP.NET MVC server side validation from client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have complete project and i want to use the mvc validation.

Here is my Save method in controller, that i called from javascript with ajax:

```
public void Save(Activity activity)
{
    using (ActivityManager manager = new ActivityManager())
    {
        manager.SaveActivity(activity);
    }
}
```

As my Save method is void, i don't want to use the Model.IsValid server side validation, because i can't and don't want to return an actionresult because of the ajax calling.

I need a client side validation, that use the server side model attributes, but i did not find any working solution.

Comment: In that case you should need to check validation constraint with in the function manually.

Comment: Do you know `remote` validation from jQuery Validation? Check this link: http://develoq.net/2011/asp-net-mvc-3-remote-validation-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to decorate your classes with data annotations and then use jQuery validation to do clientside validation:

Class Definition:

```
public class Person{

[Required(ErrorMessage="This field is required")]
public int ID {get;set;}

}
```

JS/jQuery Work:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    if($("form").valid()){
         return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i did the same, but i do not know why, but the validation returns true value on a empty string field. Is this validation using the server side model attributes validation?